# The "discrete" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[discrete](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discrete)? Seriously? What kind of a tag is that?     Too broad .

Comment: Yep, that belongs to the dubvious tags I mentioned elsewhere ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Discrete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete) means as opposed to *continuous.*

For, instance, people may ask questions about discrete electric charges, discrete spacetime, discrete energies, etc.

If discretization is vital/essential to the question then tag it with the [discrete](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discrete) tag.

Currently there is 37 questions tagged with the [discrete](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discrete) tag.

A related tag (in case of quantum theory) is the [quantization](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantization) tag.

Comment: True, but it's too broad .                                                                                                                                                                                                                              . Discrete spacetime (!) being grouped together with  discrete energy levels?

Comment: The [tag:discrete] tag (and, e.g., the [tag:fourier-transform] tag, the [tag:symmetry] tag, etc.) offers an orthogonal classification to the more traditional classifications into subjects like qmech, clas mech, stat mech, fluid dyn, etc. I find the [tag:discrete] tag useful.

Comment: @Qmechanic Just out of curiosity, don't we define meta-tags as something that couldn't stand as it's own tag and must be paired with another to make sense? Doesn't [tag:discrete] fall into that category as on it's own, it doesn't tell you anything and must be paired with [tag:spacetime], [tag:energy], etc to make sense?

Comment: @tpg2114: That "definition" isn't very precise. For example . , a tag with [tag:higgs-mechanism] would always                                         be with [tag:quantum-field-theory], [tag:String-theory], etc.